# Photointerrupter issue

Tags: circuit-analysis, infrared, photodiode, phototransistor

I have circuit with photointerrupter [GP1S092HCPIF](http://cz.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Sharp-Microelectronics/GP1S092HCPIF/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduhr%2fdkSM28CKh5LE60tKenKo5TVOzmt6Imhq7oTTARXZw%3d%3d). The documentation is rather weak and D-shape pin strange but I need a small SMD type. I hopefully identified pins correctly and when soldered on board I see it does not work.

When slot is opened then I measure collector voltage as high as 4.2V (it seems transistor is only semi-opened). When is closed then 4.8V (which seems ok, <strike>Schmitt input current Ii=100uA in datasheet</strike>, *EDIT: bug in Diodes datasheet*). Hopefully chip is connected correctly because of measured voltage Vr=1.2V identifying LED side. I'm afraid I can't check visually because of IR spectrum. I have two parallel PI circuits on board and both behaves equivalently. Soldered with heat gut at 320°C - hopefully not demaged.

Can somebody help me to detect what is wrong ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQIppf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: FYI you can use a digital camera to "visually" check an IR LED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Collector current 100 to 400 uA". Across a 1K pullup resistor, that drops 0.1 to 0.4V.

I would want to drop at least 4V across that resistor - at 100uA it should be 40 kilohms or higher (for the 5mA led current in the datasheet.

You are using a higher LED current than 5ma giving you the higher collector currents (like 700ua) you observe so there may be no need to increase R2 quite so much; 20K may be appropriate.

Comment: You are right, I was stuck the transistor has low impedance in tens of ohm when opened. But it's not true. When 18k resistor is used I have 0.2V now. Thick curtain is required to block IR, carton provides only 3.3V, plastic thick cover 4.9V. Note: gate has much less than 100uA (bug in datasheet).